# flutter undefined class 'FirebaseFirestore'

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get data from firebase firestore to the app I am building, it seems to be quite fine but I recieve this message on the console:

```
[Firestore]: The behavior for java.util.Date objects stored in Firestore is going to change AND YOUR APP MAY BREAK.
W/Firestore( 8224): To hide this warning and ensure your app does not break, you need to add the following code to your app before calling any other Cloud Firestore methods:
W/Firestore( 8224): 
W/Firestore( 8224): FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
W/Firestore( 8224): FirebaseFirestoreSettings settings = new FirebaseFirestoreSettings.Builder()
W/Firestore( 8224):     .setTimestampsInSnapshotsEnabled(true)
W/Firestore( 8224):     .build();
W/Firestore( 8224): firestore.setFirestoreSettings(settings);
```

I am using the packages

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
 import 'auth.dart';
 import 'state_rut.dart';
 import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
```

and the code ttying to get the info goes:

```
final collection = Firestore.instance.collection('regions');
collection.orderBy('region_id').getDocuments()
    .then((data){
      print(data);
    })
    .catchError((e){
       print(e);
    });
```

I wanted to use at first the one in the page https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart which apparently was the one I needed but when I type on the app the line FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance(); I get the message error undefined class 'FirebaseFirestore'.

What is it I am missing? I have everything good on the pubspec.yaml, and all the packages are working

By the way I am trying to get the data so I can build based on this a dropdownbutton

Answer (score 2):

Import this:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
```

And use this instead:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
```